# Conversion from string "Label" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Dim dtStart As Date = txtHStart_Date.Text
Dim dtEnd As Date = txtHEnd_Date.Text

Dim ts As TimeSpan = dtEnd - dtStart
Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalDays = lblHNoDays.Text)
```

When trying to write to a label I get this message:

> Conversion from string "Label" to type 'Double' is not valid.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's unclear to me what the last line means. Asigning a string to a double inside a `Console.WriteLine` call seems to make no sense to me.

Comment: not sure..got code off something like this..how else can i get it to display the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear to me what the last line means. Asigning a `string` to a `double` inside a [`Console.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/219hw6yx.aspx) call seems to make no sense to me.

What I can imagine is that you want to write something like that:

```
Dim dtStart As Date = txtHStart_Date.Text
Dim dtEnd As Date = txtHEnd_Date.Text

Dim ts As TimeSpan = dtEnd - dtStart

lblHNoDays.Text = ts.TotalDays.ToString() ' Set value to label.
Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalDays)           ' Output value to console.
```

Comment: @user1055487 You're welcome. Looking forward for your green check ;-)

Comment: @user1055487, you should accept this answer by clicking on the green check mark.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the label's text to change you need to do the following instead of Console.WriteLine:

```
lblHNoDays.Text = ts.TotalDays
```